# Could not pre-launch appium: Error: Instruments crashed on startup

Tags: iphone, appium

1. I need to inspect an iOS app in appium inspector using real iphone device.
2. I am using 1.4.8 as appium version, physical device as iphone 6 and platform version as 8.3.
3. I have enabled Enable UI Automation option under Developer option settings.
4. I have given the following parameters in iOS settings menu.
     App path: .zip format, Platform Version: 8.3, Force Device: iPhone and UDID: for that specific device

   5. If I start appium server, I am getting the below log message.

> Error Log:-
>
> Launching Appium with command: '/Applications/Appium
>   .app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node' lib/server/main.js
>   --command-timeout "7200" --pre-launch --debug-log-spacing --platform-version "8.3" --platform-name "iOS" --app "/Users/valar/work/sample_App.zip" --udid
>   "4a9b4ad142c7f308bfd3217d2fae43f9a4bc8e00" --show-ios-log
>   --device-name "iPhone 6"
>
> info: [debug] Starting Appium in pre-launch mode
>
> info: Pre-launching app info: *************************************
>   info: ************************************* info:
>   ************************************* info: ************************************* info: ************************************* info: ************************************* info: ************************************* info: ************************************* info: ****        NEW SESSION           *** info: ****        NEW SESSION           *** info: ****        NEW SESSION           *** info: ****        NEW SESSION           ***
>   info: ****        NEW SESSION           *** info: ****        NEW
>   SESSION           *** info: ****        NEW SESSION           ***
>   info: ****        NEW SESSION           *** info:
>   ************************************* info: ************************************* info: ************************************* info: ************************************* info: ************************************* info: ************************************* info: ************************************* info: *************************************
>
> info: [debug] Using local .zip from command line:
>   /Users/valar/work/sample_App.zip info: [debug] Copying local zip to
>   tmp dir
>
> info: [debug] /Users/valar/work/sample_App.zip copied to
>   /var/folders/7g/_4s8f5kx4cs1875_psp3rps00000gn/T/115725-3663-1b0sdz4/appium-app.zip
>
> info: [debug] Unzipping
>   /var/folders/7g/_4s8f5kx4cs1875_psp3rps00000gn/T/115725-3663-1b0sdz4/appium-app.zip
>
> info: [debug] Testing zip archive:
>   /var/folders/7g/_4s8f5kx4cs1875_psp3rps00000gn/T/115725-3663-1b0sdz4/appium-app.zip
>
> info: [debug] Zip archive tested clean
>
> info: [debug] Unzip successful
>
> info: [debug] Using locally extracted app:
>   /var/folders/7g/_4s8f5kx4cs1875_psp3rps00000gn/T/115725-3663-1b0sdz4/sample_App.app
>
> info: [debug] Creating new appium session
>   ab360b32-08b6-4f6b-889e-78fe9a6b88f3 info: [debug] Removing any
>   remaining instruments sockets info: [debug] Cleaned up instruments
>   socket /tmp/instruments_sock info: [debug] Auto-detecting iOS udid...
>   info: [debug] Not auto-detecting udid, running on sim
>
> info: [debug] Parsed app Info.plist (as binary)
>
> info: [debug] Parsed app Localizable.strings info: [debug] Getting
>   bundle ID from app
>
> info: [debug] Parsed app Info.plist (as binary) info: [debug] Creating
>   instruments info: [debug] Preparing uiauto bootstrap info: [debug]
>   Dynamic bootstrap dir: /Users/valar/Library/Application
>   Support/appium/bootstrap info: [debug] Dynamic env:
>   {"nodePath":"/Applications/Appium
>   .app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node","commandProxyClientPath":"/Applications/Appium
>   .app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js","instrumentsSock":"/tmp/instruments_sock","interKeyDelay":null,"justLoopInfinitely":false,"autoAcceptAlerts":false,"autoDismissAlerts":false,"sendKeyStrategy":"grouped"}
>   info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap code: // This file is automatically
>   generated. Do not manually modify! ... info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap
>   path: /Users/valar/Library/Application
>   Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-f2765f8569503e7c.js
>
> info: [debug] Reusing dynamic bootstrap:
>   /Users/valar/Library/Application
>   Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-f2765f8569503e7c.js info: [debug]
>   Attempting iOS device log capture via libimobiledevice idevicesyslog
>
> info: [debug] Creating iDevice object with udid
>   4a9b4ad142c7f308bfd3217d2fae43f9a4bc8e00
>
> info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 25 11:37:49 iPhone-6 syslog_relay[177]
>   : syslog_relay found the ASL prompt. Starting...
>
> info: [debug] App is installed.
>
> info: [debug] fullReset not requested. No need to install. info:
>   [debug] Starting command proxy.
>
> info: [debug] Instruments socket server started at
>   /tmp/instruments_sock info: [debug] Starting instruments
>
> info: [debug] Instruments is at:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments
>
> info: Launching instruments
>
> info: [debug] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID
>   4a9b4ad142c7f308bfd3217d2fae43f9a4bc8e00 info: [debug] Spawning
>   instruments with command:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate
>   -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w 4a9b4ad142c7f308bfd3217d2fae43f9a4bc8e00 com.company.iphone.
>   sample_App -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/valar/Library/Application
>   Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-f2765f8569503e7c.js" -e
>   UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments info: [debug] And extra
>   without-delay env: {} info: [debug] And launch timeouts (in ms):
>   {"global":90000}
>
> info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 253
>
> info: [debug] Killall instruments
>
> info: [debug] Instruments crashed on startup info: [debug] Attempting
>   to retry launching instruments, this is retry #1 info: [debug] Killall
>   iOS Simulator info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 25 11:37:50 iPhone-6
>   DTMobileIS[191] : Could not create service named
>   com.apple.instruments.server.services.processcontrol.posixspawn info:
>   [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 25 11:37:50 iPhone-6 DTMobileIS[191] :
>   Could not create service named
>   com.apple.instruments.server.services.launchdaemon
>
> info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 25 11:37:50 iPhone-6
>   notification_proxy[175] : 0x100494000 -[MNPLockdownConnection
>   receiveMessage]: lockdown_receive_message error!
>
> info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 25 11:37:50 iPhone-6
>   notification_proxy[175] : 0x100494000 -[MNPLockdownConnection
>   receiveMessage]: lockdown_receive_message error!
>
> info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 25 11:37:52 iPhone-6 locationd[61]
>   : Location icon should now be in state 'Active'
>
> info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 25 11:37:53 iPhone-6 CLTM[20] :
>   CLTM: _subscription 0x0, _subscribedChannels 0x0
>
> info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 25 11:37:55 iPhone-6 sample_App[151]
>   : NewRelic(4.186,0x174675e80):   NRTimer.m:94    -[NRTimer
>   timeElapsedInSeconds]
>
> info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] NRMATimer has a negative duration:
>   1440482874430.621094 => 0.000000
>
> info: Launching instruments
>
> info: [debug] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID
>   4a9b4ad142c7f308bfd3217d2fae43f9a4bc8e00
>
> info: [debug] Spawning instruments with command:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate
>   -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w 4a9b4ad142c7f308bfd3217d2fae43f9a4bc8e00 com.company.iphone.sample_App
>   -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/valar/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-f2765f8569503e7c.js" -e
>   UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments info: [debug] And extra
>   without-delay env: {} info: [debug] And launch timeouts (in ms):
>   {"global":90000}
>
> info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 253 info:
>   [debug] Killall instruments
>
> info: [debug] Instruments crashed on startup
>
> info: [debug] Attempting to retry launching instruments, this is retry
>
> ## 2 info: [debug] Killall iOS Simulator info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 25 11:37:56 iPhone-6 DTMobileIS[191] : Could not create service
>
> named com.apple.instruments.server.services.launchdaemon info:
>   [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 25 11:37:56 iPhone-6 DTMobileIS[191] :
>   Could not create service named
>   com.apple.instruments.server.services.processcontrol.posixspawn info:
>   [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 25 11:37:56 iPhone-6 notification_proxy[175]
>   : 0x100384000 -[MNPLockdownConnection receiveMessage]:
>   lockdown_receive_message error! info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 25
>   11:37:56 iPhone-6 notification_proxy[175] : 0x100384000
>   -[MNPLockdownConnection receiveMessage]: lockdown_receive_message error!
>
> info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 25 11:37:58 iPhone-6 CLTM[20] :
>   CLTM: _subscription 0x0, _subscribedChannels 0x0
>
> info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 25 11:38:01 iPhone-6 sample_App151]
>   : NewRelic(4.186,0x17487e440):   NRTimer.m:94    -[NRTimer
>   timeElapsedInSeconds]
>
> info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] NRMATimer has a negative duration:
>   1440482880235.167969 => 0.000000
>
> info: Launching instruments
>
> info: [debug] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID
>   4a9b4ad142c7f308bfd3217d2fae43f9a4bc8e00 info: [debug] Spawning
>   instruments with command:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate
>   -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w 4a9b4ad142c7f308bfd3217d2fae43f9a4bc8e00 com.company.iphone.
>   sample_App -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/valar/Library/Application
>   Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-f2765f8569503e7c.js" -e
>   UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments info: [debug] And extra
>   without-delay env: {} info: [debug] And launch timeouts (in ms):
>   {"global":90000}
>
> info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 253
>
> info: [debug] Killall instruments
>
> info: [debug] Instruments crashed on startup info: [debug] Attempting
>   to retry launching instruments, this is retry #3 info: [debug] Killall
>   iOS Simulator info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 25 11:38:02 iPhone-6
>   DTMobileIS[191] : Could not create service named
>   com.apple.instruments.server.services.processcontrol.posixspawn info:
>   [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 25 11:38:02 iPhone-6 DTMobileIS[191] :
>   Could not create service named
>   com.apple.instruments.server.services.launchdaemon
>
> info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 25 11:38:02 iPhone-6
>   notification_proxy[175] : 0x10040c000 -[MNPLockdownConnection
>   receiveMessage]: lockdown_receive_message error!
>
> info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 25 11:38:02 iPhone-6
>   notification_proxy[175] : 0x10040c000 -[MNPLockdownConnection
>   receiveMessage]: lockdown_receive_message error!
>
> info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 25 11:38:02 iPhone-6 locationd[61]
>   : Location icon should now be in state 'Region Monitoring'
>
> info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 25 11:38:03 iPhone-6 CLTM[20] :
>   CLTM: _subscription 0x0, _subscribedChannels 0x0
>
> info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 25 11:38:07 iPhone-6 sample_App[151]
>   : NewRelic(4.186,0x174675e80):   NRTimer.m:94    -[NRTimer
>   timeElapsedInSeconds]
>
> info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] NRMATimer has a negative duration:
>   1440482886151.112061 => 0.000000
>
> info: Launching instruments
>
> info: [debug] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID
>   4a9b4ad142c7f308bfd3217d2fae43f9a4bc8e00 info: [debug] Spawning
>   instruments with command:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate
>   -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w 4a9b4ad142c7f308bfd3217d2fae43f9a4bc8e00 com.company.iphone.
>   sample_App -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/valar/Library/Application
>   Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-f2765f8569503e7c.js" -e
>   UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments info: [debug] And extra
>   without-delay env: {} info: [debug] And launch timeouts (in ms):
>   {"global":90000}
>
> info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 253
>
> info: [debug] Killall instruments
>
> info: [debug] Instruments crashed on startup info: [debug] We exceeded
>   the number of retries allowed for instruments to successfully start;
>   failing launch info: [debug] Stopping iOS log capture info: [debug]
>   Running ios sim reset flow info: [debug] Killing the simulator process
>   info: [debug] Killing any other simulator daemons info: [debug]
>   Killall iOS Simulator info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 25 11:38:07 iPhone-6
>   DTMobileIS[191] : Could not create service named
>   com.apple.instruments.server.services.launchdaemon info:
>   [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 25 11:38:07 iPhone-6 DTMobileIS[191] :
>   Could not create service named
>   com.apple.instruments.server.services.processcontrol.posixspawn info:
>   [debug] On a real device; cannot clean device state info: [debug]
>   Cleaning up appium session
>
> error: Could not pre-launch appium: Error: Instruments crashed on
>   startup

Comment: this could be due the build. Did you make the build in debug mode ? if the build is done is release mode, instrument won't start and will crash

Comment: @BalajiSekar, But I am using the same build to inspect in iOS simulator. I can able to inspect in iOS simulator. In device only I am getting above error message.

Comment: Three things : 1. Are you able to access the instruments in ways other than appium script? 2. Also please make sure you have `Use Native Instruments Library` checked under Advance settings for IOS platform in Appium's UI. 3. `Enable UI Automation setting` in setting--developer

Comment: All these thing I have tried does anyone has got the solution.

Comment: Instrument crash error is because either you have created build with release and distribution mode or the UI Automation is off in developer option in iPhone or instrument path is set incorrectly... this is the f**king issue where I have lost my 3 hours.